# joomla login error message using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect, joomla

I am using below code to make AJAX call to login

```
jQuery(".loginbtn").click(function() {                 
                var data   = jQuery('#form-login').serialize();
                jQuery.ajax ({                                                          
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&task=loginauth&format=json",
                        data: data,
                        success: function(response) {
                            prompt(response.data);
                        }
                });
            });
    });
```

On **Success**, It is redirecting to profile page which is fine.
On **Login fail**, it is redirecting to homepage. I don't want this redirection. I want to stay on same page with error message.(it is not working)

In com_user component, it has User.php where this authentication and redirection is happening.

```
public function login() {
// Login failed !
            $data['remember'] = (int) $options['remember'];

            $app->setUserState('users.login.form.data', $data);
            $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login', false));
}
```

If I am commenting this code. it is still redirecting to home page. I want error message in my ajax response. How can I get it?

Comment: try changing the beggining to: 
`jQuery(".loginbtn").click(function(e) {      e.preventDefault(); `

Comment: if I am using it..it is not redirecting even if user entered correct login credentials

Comment: you would have to implement that manually. The thing is that you ajax the login credentials to the server and then browser does a standard call to the same page which causes redirection in both cases. You will have to prevent the default action, which is submitting the form, and then manually identify if the login was successful and redirect the user

Comment: then what is the use of **loginauh** AJAX call..:(...I think it is inbuilt way to do AJAX calls for login

Comment: I think I have to write PHP code :(...only javascript is not enough

Comment: the use of the ajax would be to log the person in, not to redirect them. And yes, very likely that you have to write some php code that would return link to the page or something like that upon successful login